# MySQL vs. Oracle - @ http://sqlfiddle.com/

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm running the below SQL code at http://sqlfiddle.com/

If I pick Oracle, I get an error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

However, it works fine with MySQL option. Has anyone experienced it? Do you know what I'm doing wrong? I double-checked my code and I don't see any obvious issues.

```
Create Table Variables1 (name varchar(3), value1 int);
Create Table Expressions (left_operand varchar(3), operator ENUM('>', '<', '='), right_operand varchar(3));

insert into Variables1 (name, value1) values ('x', 66);
insert into Variables1 (name, value1) values ('y', 77);

insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '>', 'y');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '<', 'y');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '=', 'y');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('y', '>', 'x');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('y', '<', 'x');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '=', 'x');
```

Comment: ENUM in Oracle? seriously? where you have found this? use common VARCHAR with according CHECK constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support ENUM. Use according string-type column + CHECK constraint.

```sql
Create Table Variables1 (name varchar(3), value1 int);
Create Table Expressions (left_operand varchar(3), 
                          operator CHAR(1),
                          CHECK ( operator IN ('>', '<', '=') ), 
                          right_operand varchar(3));

insert into Variables1 (name, value1) values ('x', 66);
insert into Variables1 (name, value1) values ('y', 77);

insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '>', 'y');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '<', 'y');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '=', 'y');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('y', '>', 'x');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('y', '<', 'x');
insert into Expressions (left_operand, operator, right_operand) values ('x', '=', 'x');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4ca38

PS. MySQL 8.0.16+ supports this syntax too (rather than previous versions which parses but ignores CHECK constraints).

Remember - in shown code the column `operator` allows NULLs, and this value matches the CHECK constraint expression. If it is not safe for you then define the column as NOT NULL additionally.